# How are all the tools that I'm using related to one another?

Tags: selenium, rspec, capybara, selenium-chromedriver

So I've been automating tests for some time, but I honestly don't think I completely understand how the tools I am using are fundamentally related to one another.  I actually feel a bit embarrassed but this was the toolbox handed down to me and I just ran with it.  I've since put it to incredibly good use, which I'm very grateful for.

So I'm using the following, which if I'm not mistaken is fairly common nowadays: `selenium-webdriver`, `rspec`, `capybara`, `chromedriver`

What is the relationship between all of these that allow me to accomplish what I do on a daily basis?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. RSpec is the test runner framework.
2. Capybara is a tool for emulating user behavior on a web page, and verifying the existence of content on those web pages, there are a number of drivers for it.  It comes with rack-test and selenium-webdriver drivers.
3. Selenium-webdriver is used to integrate with the selenium web automation framework, it supports using firefox out of the box.
4. Chromedriver allows selenium-webdriver to control googles chrome browser

Comment: Thank you for the simple explanation.  This is perfect!